# Prove $\forall n \ge 3$ there is a non-commutative group of exponent $n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove $\forall n \ge 3$ there is a non-commutative group of exponent
>   $n$

The exponent of a group $G$ is the lowest $n$ such that $x^n=e, \forall x \in G$

I cannot use strong theorem like classification of finite groups, so I tried using permutation group to get the result, to no avail.

Comment: how about the group of primitive n-th roots of unity?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki It is commutative

Comment: ah, right. I didn't read the question carefully, sorry

Comment: The dihedral groups show this for any even $n$: If $n$ is even, then the symmetry group of the regular $n$-gon (including reflections) has exponent $n$.

Comment: For odd prime $p$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254342

Comment: @Watson, if you can do it for odd primes, you can do it for any odd number $n$, just by taking the direct product of a non-commutative group of exponent $p$ for some $p$ dividing $n$, and the cyclic group of order $n$, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: this seems fine to me. Combining this result with Arthur's comment gives the full answer.